# How can I make this code not so redundant

Tags: python-3.x, loops, exception

Much of this code seems redundant to me and I was wondering if it could be simplified. Here are a few key places that I believe could be simplified.

1- The error exceptions are the same for all 5 loops
2- for the last 3 sections, Construct the threads, start the threads and wait until they are finished. Is their a way to make this section dynamic, so theses 3 sections can increase or decrease based on the number of loops being multithreaded?

Here is the code

```
def write_prices():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_data(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Stock Prices\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except ValueError:
            print (" ValueError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print (" FileNotFoundError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except KeyError:
            print (" KeyError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except IndexError:
            print (" IndexError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])       
        except NameError:
            print (" NameError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except HTTPError:
            print (" HTTPError " )



def write_incomes():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_income_statement(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Income Statement\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except ValueError:
            print (" ValueError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print (" FileNotFoundError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except KeyError:
            print (" KeyError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except IndexError:
            print (" IndexError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])       
        except NameError:
            print (" NameError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except HTTPError:
            print (" HTTPError " )

def write_balance_sheet():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_balance_sheet(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\Balance Sheet\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except ValueError:
            print (" ValueError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print (" FileNotFoundError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except KeyError:
            print (" KeyError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except IndexError:
            print (" IndexError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])       
        except NameError:
            print (" NameError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except HTTPError:
            print (" HTTPError " )



def write_cash_flow():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_cash_flow(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\Cash Flow\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except ValueError:
            print (" ValueError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print (" FileNotFoundError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except KeyError:
            print (" KeyError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except IndexError:
            print (" IndexError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])       
        except NameError:
            print (" NameError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except HTTPError:
            print (" HTTPError " )

def write_stats():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_stats(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\Statistics\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except ValueError:
            print (" ValueError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print (" FileNotFoundError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except KeyError:
            print (" KeyError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except IndexError:
            print (" IndexError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])       
        except NameError:
            print (" NameError :%s" %np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
        except HTTPError:
            print (" HTTPError " )

# construct the threads
t1 = threading.Thread(target=write_prices)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=write_incomes)
t3 = threading.Thread(target=write_balance_sheet)
t4 = threading.Thread(target=write_cash_flow)
t5 = threading.Thread(target=write_stats)

# start the threads
[t.start() for t in (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)]

# wait until they finish
[t.join() for t in (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first function can be rewritten as:

```
def write_prices():
    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(0,len(stock_ticker.Symbol))):
        try:
            ticker_df=pd.DataFrame(get_data(np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i]))
            ticker_df.to_csv("E:\\Stock Database\\Stock Prices\\%s.txt"%np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])

        except (ValueError, FileNotFoundError, KeyError, IndexError, NameError, HTTPError) as e:
            print (e, np.array(stock_ticker.Symbol)[i])
```